# EWS StreamingSubscriptionConnection for Office 365 does not work correct

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

We have a problem with StreamingSubscriptionConnection for Office 365.
The same code works perfect for any other Exchange versions but does not work for Exchange Online.

The problem is:
I try to install StreamingSubscriptionConnection to 3 different exchange folders.
With first two folders connection successfully installed, but for 3 folder - application complete hang off.
I could change order of folders to connect, its always connect to any 2 first folders, but on third its always locked.

I prepare complete example for StreamingSubscriptionConnection. It could use any Exchange versions.
And it make a log of EWS requests and Responses.
On our side - the code execution stops on StreamingSubscriptionRequest

[Here is my example project](http://www.mks-goliath.com/support/Office365PublicExample.zip)

Please Help us.

Thanks
Denis

Answer (score 0):

I'v got solution from Glen Scales (MCC, MVP)
Maybe it will usefull for someone.

The .net ServicePointManager restricts the number of connections to 2 concurrent connections by default, because streaming connections are always open I would say this is your problem so I would suggest you increase this value to start eg

ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 300;